# High covariance data for linear model, and PCA in R

Tags: r, regression, correlation, pca, covariance

I have 4 set of data Y X1 X2 X3 in same length where I need to perform a model selection of linear regression on Y~ X1+X2+X3-1.
However, there are significant covariance between X2 and X3. $Cov(X2,X3)=0.98$, and $Cov(X1,X2)=0.7,Cov(X1,X3)=0.2$.

I tried to use nls where it gave me something like $Y=0.8X1+0.2X3$, where by using AIC and BIC I obtained the most suitable model by $Y=X3$.

My first question was:

1. What's the proper way to determine the (first order) linear model in this case.(high covariance.)

I encountered a possible solution called PCA.(principal component analysis)

by using commend like

```
prcomp(X,center=TRUE,scale=TRUE)
```

where

```
X=data.frame(X1,X2,X3)
```

I also obtained a 2*2 rotation matrix where it said the column was the eigenvector, and a graph by using the code

```
biplot(prcomp(X2,center=TRUE,scale=TRUE), scale = 0).
```

However, I wasn't sure it this is going to be anyway helpful, specifically, how to use the 3*3 rotation matrix, because I need to regression with respect to all 3 data.(They are in fact independent market data, but with high covariance).
Suppose the rotation matrix $=A$, should I use$XA,AX,A^TX$ or $XA^T$?

Answer (score 1):

the problem when you use PCA is that you can't interpret your coefficients anymore. PCA reduces dimensions and combines 2 variables into 1 new variable. For that it uses the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the covariance matrix. In that way two highly correlated variables can be decorrelated and used together in one model. The disadvantage is that after in your linear regression you will have a new variable that you can't interpret. That's also the reason why you have less variables after PCA, because PCA combines variables into a new one.

If two variables are highly correlated you don't need to include both. Just include one of the two, as adding the second one will not explain more of the variance in Y. 
Have you tried lasso regression?